# Fetching huge datasets from Oracle in Python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

In one of my projects I am fetching data from Oracle database using Python. The dataset has millions of rows, which takes around 40-50 minutes every day.

I am using the `cx_Oracle` library in Python. Is there any way to do reduce time. Maybe something like partition or parallel processing?

```py
Conn = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, server)
a= pd.read_sql(sql_query, Conn)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without the query, table layout, etc… there's no way to properly advise you on how to optimally read the data.

Comment: Processing the data in smaller chunks may help, e.g. in batches of 100k rows. For this, set `pandas.read_sql(sql, con, chunksize=100_000)`. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Review the cx_Oracle doc [Tuning cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html) doc too.  The biggest tuning impact when fetching data over a network is the value of`cursor.arraysize`, which may or may not be what chunksize sets.